# SQL Server: Finding date given EndDate and # Days, excluding days from specific date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a `TableA` in a database similar to the following:

```
Id | Status   | Start       | End

1  | Illness  | 2013-04-02  | 2013-04-23
2  | Illness  | 2013-05-05  | 2014-01-01
3  | Vacation | 2014-02-01  | 2014-03-01
4  | Illness  | 2014-03-08  | 2014-03-09
5  | Vacation | 2014-05-05  | NULL
```

Imagine it's keeping track of a specific user's "Away" days. Given the following Inputs:

1. `SomeEndDate` (Date),
2. `NumDays` (Integer)

I want to find the `SomeStartDate` (Date) that is `Numdays` non-illness days from `EndDate`. In other words, say I am given a `SomeEndDate` value '2014-03-10' and a `NumDays` value of 60; the matching SomeStartDate would be:

1. 2014-03-10 to 2014-03-09 = 1
2. 2014-03-08 to 2014-01-01 = 57
3. 2013-05-05 to 2013-05-03 = 2

So, at 60 non-illness days, we get a `SomeStartDate` of '2013-05-03'. IS there any easy way to accomplish this in SQL? I imagine I could loop each day, check whether or not it falls into one of the illness ranges, and increment a counter if not (exiting the loop after counter = @numdays)... but that seems wildly inefficient. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand your table, but I think I would try to do it in two separate calculations.  Subtract your number of days from your enddate. Calculate the number of illness days, and add that to your prior result.

Comment: Be very careful about how you interpret the ranges.  Quite often, date-only ranges are fully closed intervals.  For example, March 9th to March 10th would usually be considered *two* days, not one.  (Of course, if there is a time involved, then that's completely different.)

Comment: Andrew - I had thought about that somewhat earlier, but couldn't convince myself it was good approach (maybe I was wrong!). If I take 60 days from the EndDate and add @count illness days that lay within to get StartDate = dateadd(d, -(60+@count), EndDate), my new StartDate may land within another illness range, or contain additional illness days. So I would loop this until the new StartDate didn't land within an illness range or contain additional illness days?

Comment: Matt - I appreciate the reminder. I was more concerned about finding a general approach that was reasonably efficient or didn't looked super hacked together, but I'll keep that in mind when I actually write this out.

Answer (score 1):

Make a Calendar table that has a list of all the dates you will ever care about.

```
SELECT MIN([date])
FROM (
  SELECT TOP(@NumDays) [date]
  FROM Calendar c
  WHERE c.Date < @SomeEndDate
    AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM TableA a
      WHERE c.Date BETWEEN a.Start AND a.END
        AND Status = 'Illness'
    )
  ORDER BY c.Date
) t
```

The Calendar table method lets you also easily exclude holidays, weekends, etc.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion! :) It certainly feels cleaner than what I would have otherwise attempted. I'll try it out now.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2012:

Try this solution:

```
DECLARE @NumDays INT = 70, @SomeEndDate DATE = '2014-03-10';

SELECT  
    [RangeStop],
    CASE 
        WHEN RunningTotal_NumOfDays <= @NumDays THEN [RangeStart]
        WHEN RunningTotal_NumOfDays - Current_NumOfDays <= @NumDays THEN DATEADD(DAY, -(@NumDays - (RunningTotal_NumOfDays - Current_NumOfDays))+1, [RangeStop])
    END AS [RangeStart]
FROM (
    SELECT  
        y.*, 
        DATEDIFF(DAY, y.RangeStart, y.RangeStop) AS Current_NumOfDays,
        SUM( DATEDIFF(DAY, y.RangeStart, y.RangeStop) ) OVER(ORDER BY y.RangeStart DESC) AS RunningTotal_NumOfDays
    FROM (
        SELECT  LEAD(x.[End]) OVER(ORDER BY x.[End] DESC) AS RangeStart, -- It's previous date because of "ORDER BY x.[End] DESC"
            x.[Start] AS RangeStop
        FROM (
            SELECT   @SomeEndDate AS [Start], '9999-12-31' AS [End]
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  x.[Start], x.[End]
            FROM    @MyTable AS x
            WHERE   x.[Status] = 'Illness'
            AND     x.[End] <= @SomeEndDate
        ) x
    ) y
) z
WHERE RunningTotal_NumOfDays - Current_NumOfDays <= @NumDays;

/*
Output:
RangeStop  RangeStart
---------- ----------
2014-03-10 2014-03-09
2014-03-08 2014-01-01
2013-05-05 2013-05-03
*/
```

Note #1: `LEAD(End)` will return the previous End date (previous because of ORDER BY End DESC)

Note #2: `DATEDIFF(DAY, RangeStart, RangeStop)` computes the num. of days between current start (alias `x.RangeStop`) and "previous" end (alias `x.RangeStar`) => `Current_NumOfDays`

Note #3: `SUM( Current_NumOfDays )` computes a running total thus: 1 + 66 + (3)

Note #4: I've used `@NumOfDays = 70` (not `60`)